# Reading sites with WebClient

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to read two sites with C# WebClient.
One site is OK and the other one does not return results.
I read about the WebClient and I can't see any reason for it not the read the site (when checking the site in browser it's OK).

This is my very simple code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
   System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
   string webData = wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.co.il/");
  string webData2 = wc.DownloadString("https://www.022.co.il/BRPortal/br/P004.jsp?vhost=www.3k.2016.neveganpt.edu1.org.il&key=n1F08wuIttY1rox0INBe1478179213794&hijkses=false");
}
```

Did I miss some parameter for the second site? Is there something in it that demands special care?

Comment: Have you tried getting the non-working URL first? Have you tried accessing that URL from your browser, or using something like `wget`? Perhaps the problem is with the web site and not your code. Do you get an error from the second URL? Have you checked to see what the error means?

Comment: @JimMischel Ok I remember that I did it like this in the past, I will delete my answer.

Comment: When I try it from my browser, I get a timeout error. wget returns a 443, which is an unknown error code, and retries. Seems like there's a problem with the web site, or with your request parameters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be caused by a malfunctioning web site rather than a problem in code.

Comment: @JimMischel But When I am surfing from my browser I get the page with out a problem. Maybe the webpage have some security check that you are from Israel and surfing from a real browser?

Comment: Yes, it could be checking your User-Agent string, although I was unable to get to it from my browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656049/how-to-set-user-agent-in-webclient for how to set the User-Agent string in `WebClient`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write a method for this?

```
public string GetHtml(string url)
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        return wc.DownloadString(url);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var webData = GetHtml("http://www.google.co.il/");
var webData2 = GetHtml("https://www.022.co.il/BRPortal/br....");
```