# Issue receiving a webpage with WebClient / HttpClient in .Net C#

Tags: c#, ssl, connection, httpclient

I would like to perform a very simple task: get the content of https://www.onvista.de into a string. This was working fine but something has changed recently. The code I'm using:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.onvista.de");
```

results in:

```
Run-time exception: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

Playground link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ghAW0

All my browsers can display the page, but I'm just not able to get it in code. I suspect something with the SSL settings, but am not sure about this. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Try setting a user agent string to make it look like the request is coming from a browser

Comment: Gave it a try and that worked. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656049/how-to-set-user-agent-in-webclient

Comment: Thx stuartd, all working now, many thanks!